# NodeJS + mysql: Select query returning individual objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have been using the `mysql` NPM package for many months and have not faced any issues. But this code is acting strange.

```
 using(connectionPool.getSqlConnection(), function(connection) {
        return connection.queryAsync('SELECT * from table_name');
    }).spread(function(rows, fields) {
        console.log('Rows: %j', rows);
        console.log('Fields: %j', fields);
        res.json(rows);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I know that there are 50 rows in the table. But I am getting only 1 in `rows`. Also, strangely `fields` has the 2nd row. Any idea why this is happening? I have used the same query elsewhere with no problems.

**EDIT**

I fiddled around a little bit and found that each row is coming as a separate object. So if I change the code to the following:

```
 using(connectionPool.getSqlConnection(), function(connection) {
        return connection.queryAsync('SELECT * from table_name');
    }).spread(function(r1, r2, r3, r4) {
        console.log('Rows: %j', r1);
        console.log('Rows: %j', r2);
        console.log('Rows: %j', r3);
        console.log('Rows: %j', r4);
        res.json(rows);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

each of r1, r2, r3, r4, ... have a single row object.

Comment: I believe that's the behaviour of the `spread` function. How about simply using `.query`? See the [documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction)

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself so that it helps someone else.

```
using(connectionPool.getSqlConnection(), function(connection) {
        return connection.queryAsync('SELECT * from table_name');
    }).then(function(rows) {
        console.log('Rows: %j', rows);
        res.json(rows);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

This works.